# app.functions is not a function in Firebase Angular SDK functions, HttpsCallable

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions, angularfire2

i'm struggling a bit setting up firebase functions within my angular project.

I'm trying to do the following:

```
const callable = this.fns.httpsCallable('getLandingPageText');

console.log(callable);

callable(({ params }))
  .subscribe((result: any) => console.log(result));
```

So this results into:

```
ERROR TypeError: app.functions is not a function
at angular-fire-compat-functions.js:32:29
```

i've initialized my firebaseApp in the app.module and also imported the AngularFireFunctionsModule in there like as you can see here:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig),
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    AngularFireFunctionsModule,
    MainToolModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
  ],
  providers: [AuthService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

The modules are imported from `@angular/fire/compat` The service where the httpsCallable is used is within the MainToolModule.

So far i've had no issues with the other modules like the FireAuth / Database module (use this within the tool module itself).

Does anyone have an idea?

EDIT:

The `this.fns` comes from the constructor in the service:

```
constructor(private fns: AngularFireFunctions) {}
```

which is imported from

```
import { AngularFireFunctions } from '@angular/fire/compat/functions';
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you resolve this somehow?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by updating my @angular/fire npm package.

For Angular Version 16, you have to install @angular/fire Version 16.